# Peppermint OS Can't drag and drop to terminal?

Tags: terminal, vmware, drag-and-drop

I have been using ubuntu quite a while. Drag and drop allowed me to get the path to the terminal which is so convenient.

Peppermint OS doesn't seem to have this functionality. Why can't I drag and drop to the terminal on Peppermint?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Since you seem to have found the answer to the drag and drop issue (the fact that the two OSs use different terminals), I have removed the other questions from your post so this Q can be specific. Please post your other questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses the gnome terminal, peppermintOS has been using sakura for the last several releases.